# Jruby Gem For Heroku

Tags: ruby, jruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Jruby app on Heroku. Unfortunately, when I try to install gem for Heroku using jruby, I get following error:

```
/proj/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/1.8/mkmf.rb:7: JRuby does not support native extensions. Check wiki.jruby.org for alternatives. (NotImplementedError)
    from /proj/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/1.8/mkmf.rb:1:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1
ERROR:  Error installing heroku:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Is there a way to install heroku gem for Jruby? Any help will be great.
Cheers

Comment: Hi Priyank, would you like to do freelancing in Jruby project?

Comment: @TanuGarg Thanks for reaching out. Contact me on priyaaank at gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `heroku` gem relies on some other gems that have native C extensions, which of course don't work in JRuby. <s>I'm also reasonably sure that heroku doesn't support JRuby anyway.</s>

Comment: Heroku does support Jruby now: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/12/13/run_jruby_on_heroku_right_now

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can't, but - [some info](http://domhackers.blogspot.com/2009/05/heroku-client-on-jruby-part-i.html)
And also google app engine supports jRuby (I'm in love with heroku though :) )